# Build getting succeeded, but test suite is not getting executed from pom.xml with mvn test

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, pom.xml

I am trying to execute the maven test from pom.xml . All my test are written in testng.xml file and I am able to invoke testng.xml file alone and test is getting executed as expected. But when I try to execute testng.xml from pom.xml using mvn test, though I have called testng.xml file from maven sure fire plugin, only the build is getting succeed and test is not getting executed.

Please find my pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>


     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>        
     <configuration>       
         
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


</project>
```

And below in testng.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<parameter name = "DemoUrl" value = "https://xxxx.com/" />
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="helixpackage.Demo.CreateProjectTest">
       <methods>
       <include name="ProjectCreationTest" />
      </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Below is the Folder structure:

[Folder structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyZ5R.png)

While executing mvn test I can see only Build get succeeded and test is not triggered

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for helixpackage:EYHelix:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin @ line 140, column 14
[WARNING] 'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin @ line 149, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< helixpackage:Demo >------------------------
[INFO] Building Demo0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ Demo---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Jeby.Jacob\git\Demo1\Demo\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) @ Demo---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ Demo---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Jeby.Jacob\git\Demo1\Demo\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Demo---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ Demo---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.988 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-23T20:21:28+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is going wrong here. I tried to debug but not getting the exact issue.

Comment: try running mvn with -X option to get more logs

Comment: You have added different testing frameworks JUnit Jupiter, TestNG which should be used? You have to decide to use only one...and remove the other one... Also show us one of your tests

Comment: @khmarbaise surefire documentation is stating that "Tests in your test source directory can be any combination of the following:    TestNG, JUnit (3.8, 4.x or 5.x), POJO"

Comment: Without your testing class there is no way to help...apart from you quotes from docs which do not really help here...You should also cleanup your pom file from warnings etc...